# How to resize the element so it is responsive? html/css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I want to make the element resizable, meaning it should change size depending on the size of the device screen.

Here is the code:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&family=Oswald:wght@500&family=Pacifico&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,900;1,500&display=swap');



.svg-file path {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: rgb(1, 36, 133);
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    stroke-dasharray: 550;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    animation: animate-zlogo 2s linear infinite;
}

.svg-file.z-logo svg {
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
    transform: scale(2);
}

.svg-file h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto", cursive;
    transform: translate(0, 50px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #044d77;
}

.svg-file span {
    animation: dots 2.5s steps(6, end) infinite;
    font-size: 5em;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0, 65px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    background-color: rgb(5, 46, 80);
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
}

@keyframes fadein-fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes animate-zlogo {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -50;
    }

    20% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 550;
        fill: transparent;
    }

    40% {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
    }

    60% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
        fill: #05f7f9;    
        }

    80% {
        stroke-width: 0;
       fill: #05f7f9;
    }

    100% {
        /* stroke-dashoffset: 0; */
        stroke-width: 3;
        fill: transparent;
    }
}
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.z-logo svg {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.z-logo::before {
  content: "";
    top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
        <div class="svg-file z-logo">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 133 133" width="133" height="133">
                <g id="H">
                    <path d="M45.33 78.22L87.67 78.22L87.67 133L121.05 133L121.05 0L87.67 0L87.67 49.33L45.33 49.33L45.33 0L11.95 0L11.95 133L45.33 133L45.33 78.22Z"
                     fill="#47AF9A" />
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem I am facing is that whenever I go on a small device like a mobile phone, the animation appears like this:

[image]

I want the animation to be like in the code I sent, any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you can try using `calc(vw + px)` combining `vw` and `px` for each of your size value. So it will have a base size in `px` too and adding the `vw` to follow the viewport size. Other than that `@media` will be the other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

Remove the `width` and `height` from the `.svg-file` div in HTML.. and in CSS add this:

```
.svg-file {
  width:50vw;
  max-width:450px;
}
```

and for the `.z-logo::before`, set `width: 60vw` and `height` to the same value to `height: 60vw`

Also add a `max-width` and `max-height` for `.z-logo::before` to the maximum allowed width in order to avoid extra large issue

```
.z-logo::before {
  width: 60vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 60vw;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/RwoZdgO?editors=0100)

Comment: thats not what i am looking for, right now the animation is the size of the screen but I want the animation to be the same size as in the code I sent, but when the screen gets smaller the animation should also get smaller and adjust to that size. But initially, it should start with the size I sent in the code.

Comment: those `max-width` and `max-height` above are just for demonstration purpose, adjust them as you like,  check this for a `200px x 200px` black square and a `133px` H https://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/vYyJPvo?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to look into @media queries. Link for reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Bootstrap provides excellent support for responsive design, which is also done using @media queries. here is the link-
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#media-queries

Answer (score 0):

If you give a percentage size to `.svg-file` that will make it scale with the page. It's unclear what you want the end result to be but that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try including this style:

```
`html, 
body, 
#preloader { 
height: 100%; 
width:100%; 
position:relative 
}`
```